# Is stack pointer check for alignment during local variable definition?

Tags: c, stack, alignment

I see some `#pragma`, `__attribute__` and `alignas` methods for aligning, but the question is it, Does the compiler-generated code check the memory address (Stack pointer) in runtime and add padding if alignment criteria are not met? Does this result in increased processing overhead during function calls?

I think this action will be done in the execution of the code, that is, the Stack pointer will be checked. But I did not see anywhere to mention this.

Comment: It's done by the compiler. There's no run-time checking in C except what you write, and what breaks the OS.

Comment: If it's not checked, then how can local elements be aligned?

Comment: The addresses are aligned by arithmetic.

Comment: Check the generated code, you'll usually see something at the beginning of the function that aligns the stack pointer. Everything else is relative to that.

Comment: Assuming we are calling a series of function pointers that change at runtime, then the compiler wouldn't have a basis for stack-related computations.

Comment: The compiler knows the amount of stack needed by a function, and rounds that up to the alignment. The received stack pointer will already be aligned.

Comment: Before one function can call another, the "return to" memory address must be put on the stack, therefore _alignment_ for the stack pointer is calculated by the compiler at the point of the caller. Suggest you read the Wikipedia article about "Calling Conventions".

Comment: Calling Conventions is good point. I understand it. Thanks @Fe2O3.
The point is that at the beginning of each function call, the address is guaranteed to be aligned, so when the base address is always aligned, the compiler can easily align local elements without any additional checks.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler ensures that all automatic objects are aligned as they require.<sup>1</sup> Typically this is implemented in one of two ways:

- The rules about managing the stack are such that the stack frame of a function always has the strictest alignment required for objects with a fundamental alignment requirement. For example, if the rules always align the stack frame to a multiple of 16 bytes, then the compiler may put an object with a four-byte alignment requirement at offsets of 0, 4, 8, or 12 relative to the stack frame and know that it will be properly aligned without further checks or adjustments.
- For objects with stricter alignment requirements than is generally required for the stack frame, the compiler generates instructions to locate them as required. For example, if the rules always align the stack frame to a multiple of eight bytes and the compiler is to reserve space for an object with a 16-byte alignment requirement, it may generate an instruction to clear the low four bits of the stack pointer, thus decreasing it to a multiple of 16 bytes if it is not already a multiple of 16 bytes.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This is true at least for all fundamental alignment requirements, which includes all the ordinary types specified by the C standard. An implementation may have additional types with extended alignment requirements, and the C standard does not require implementations to suppose those alignment requires for all storage durations.

Answer (score 1):

> I see some `#pragma`, `__attribute__` and `alignas` methods for aligning,

Note well that of these, only `alignas` (`_Alignas`) is a standard means of modulating object alignment.  (`#pragma` itself is standard, but there is no standard alignment-management pragma.)

> but the question is it, Does the compiler-generated code check the memory address (Stack pointer) in runtime and add padding if alignment criteria are not met?

Generally speaking, that's not feasible.

The alignment of an object is a function of its address, and an object's address is a fundamental part of its identity.  You cannot change an object's address at runtime.

Moreover, the vast majority of C compilers produce binary code that refers to automatic variables only by their addresses (typically relative to a stack pointer).  You cannot change such a variable's address at runtime because you would have to find and modify all relevant appearances of its address, which would require the program to modify its own code.  Although self-modifying software is possible in a general sense, it is not compatible with typical C execution environments, wherein the memory containing executable code is protected against writing.

> Does this result in increased processing overhead during function calls?

No, because it does not happen.  And avoiding unnecessary overhead is a good reason to avoid a mechanism that required such runtime checks (if another reason were required).

> I think this action will be done in the execution of the code, that is, the Stack pointer will be checked.

I have no idea why you would suppose so.  I cannot think of a single advantage to that approach.

The compiler knows the needed alignment at compile time.  It is well positioned to provide for appropriate object alignments at compile time, and it needs somehow to provide appropriately for *all* objects' alignments (those with their default alignment, too).  What is to be gained by initially, *knowingly*, giving objects the wrong alignment, and inserting code to change that alignment dynamically at runtime?

> But I did not see anywhere to mention this.

I'm not aware of any explicit documentation forbidding there being a dynamic element to aligning objects in memory.  My previous comments notwithstanding, I can imagine ways that something along the lines you describe could be implemented.  In practice, no compiler you're likely ever to meet does such a thing.  I would not expect even a C interpreter, which in some sense does process C declarations dynamically, to implement the kind of behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It is not done at runtime, only compile time:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int __attribute__((aligned(17))) x;
    x = rand();
    return x;
}
```

Output:

```
<source>:9:5: error: requested alignment '17' is not a positive power of 2
    9 |     int __attribute__((aligned(17))) x;
      |     ^~~
```

Comment: My question was at a point when the alignment request was correctly provided, and then I understood how the program behaves at runtime by studying the Calling Conventions.
The point is that it's right before calling any function that the address is always aligned, so as a result, alignment is easily achieved at the beginning of each function without any additional checks.